# Checkboxes in text angular not saving

Tags: angularjs, textangular

I'm using text-angular to save html-based content into database and i want to save checkboxes with the checked attribute on them. I've tried to use the input field like below but text-angular doesnt render checkboxes with checked attribute. Is there any way to do this without doing pure css checkboxes?

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

**EDIT**: The code I am using:

```html
<text-angular data-ng-model="example_content" placeholder="Content..." 
              rows="5">
```

And inside the `textarea` of the `text-angular` directive, I am trying to insert the `input` from above but it renders without `checked` attribute

Comment: provide full code in which you have problem

Comment: @Gaurav it's just the text-angular directive. and inside the textarea of the directive i am inserting the input from the post but it doesnt render it checked. it renders the checkbox but unchecked. I edited the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up in [`text-angular`](https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular)'s sanitizer library `textAngular-sanitize.js` to find out that the [**`checked`** attribute isn't part of their **`htmlAttrs`** attribute map](https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular/blob/master/src/textAngular-sanitize.js#L226).

Hence, the only option we're left with is to override the sanitizer JS file with the edit. Moreover, you can add other attributes/tags if you want (Do consider vulnerabilities though!)

Here's the [**working example plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SWfuJ6Em12SQZ2GDmzs0?p=preview) forked from official `text-Angular` plunker. Notice the `ta-sanitize.js` included in plunker which is modified version of their `textAngular-sanitize.js`

Hope this helps!

Comment: that works. ty very much. i dont need other attributes/tags. i am using mostly basic html so i guess there is no problem with just the "checked" attribute

Comment: @IonuțZamfir glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using ng-click

```html
   <input type='checkbox' ng-click='onsaveValue()' ng-model="saveValue">
```

Comment: @tanmay you are right, thats what i am trying to do